# progress bar is not working properly when i download a task with NSURLSessionDataTask?

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

when i started to download a file using  NSURLSessionDataTask the progress is not working for some times.Then after completion of downloading only progress bar showing with full blue.

my code

```
 - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler

  {
completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
 NSLog(@"Response:%@ \n", response);
self.progressView.progress=0.0f;

   self.downloadSize=[response expectedContentLength];
self.dataToDownload=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}


  - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  {


[self.dataToDownload appendData:data];

self.progressView.progress=[ self.dataToDownload length ]/_downloadSize;
}



  - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask  *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {

if (error) {


    // Handle error
}
else {

 }
```

these are the codes i used to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Should ensure all UI updates run in main queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   self.progressView.progress=[ self.dataToDownload length ]/_downloadSize;
});
```

Comment: how to add resume and cancel downloading

Comment: Consider resume, cancel & suspend method
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSessionTask/suspend

ps: give me a tick mark if my solution works, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @TonyNguyen can you please resolve my issue, where i am getting the expectedContentLength  -1
[https://stackoverflow.com/q/61390787/12393426]