# Error during Showing the file download progress with NSURLSessionDataTask in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I am trying to show the download progress the progress bar as well as on the label in my app.The code is in objective c. But i am getting negative progress value. Please help my to resolve the issue. Please look into my code and output, i have mentioned below. My code is:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        float progress = 0.0f;
        [self.progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
        self.lblProgressCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%",progress*100];
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",progress*100]);

    });

    _downloadSize=[response expectedContentLength];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    if(!_dataToDownload){

        _dataToDownload=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    }

    [_dataToDownload appendData:data];

    float progress = [ _dataToDownload length ]/_downloadSize;

    NSLog(@"_downloadSize is: %f",_downloadSize);
    NSLog(@"_dataToDownload.length is: %lu",(unsigned long)[ 
        _dataToDownload length ]);
    NSLog(@"progress  : %f",progress);
    NSLog(@"progress is : %@",[NSString 
        stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",progress*100]);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
        self.lblProgressCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%",progress*100];

    });

}
```

I am getting output like:-

```
_downloadSize is: -1.000000
_dataToDownload.length is: 9321
 progress  : -9321.000000
 progress is : -932100

_downloadSize is: -1.000000
_dataToDownload.length is: 15352
 progress  : -15352.000000
 progress is : -1535200
```

Comment: What are the values of `_dataToDownload.length` and `_downloadSize`? Is `_downloadSize` `NSURLResponseUnknownLength`?

Comment: Hi @Willeke, i have edited the question with all the output, please look into it.

Comment: Is the question why `_downloadSize` is `-1`? Please read the documentation of `expectedContentLength`.